# Laravel 5.8 - boot method of trait causing Segmentation fault in seed

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.8

I have a `Trait` which I include in a number of classes to automatically set the id of 'creator' or `updater`. I do this using the `static` methods `creating` and `updating` in the `trait` boot method.

During seeding the seeder fails with:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This error relates to recursion / infinite loops if I understood other posts.

I know the issue is in the `boot` method of the trait but I have not figured out why / how to fix it. If I comment it out, seeds fine but the ids are not set.

My `trait` `GlobalMethods` boot method is:

```
protected static function bootGlobalMethods() {

    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function ($obj) {
        $obj->creator_id = Auth::user()->id;
    });

    static::updating(function ($obj) {
        $obj->updater_id = Auth::user()->id;
    });

}
```

What have I missed? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit was:

```
parent::boot();
```

Removed it and works.